# lxml etree replaces <em></em> with <em/>

Tags: python, django, html-parsing, lxml

I have a blog where I save blog posts as a HTML string (basically text of html elements) on a database. Ex: I created a blog post which resulted in following string as my blog post content.

```
<p>asdasd</p><p><em></em><div>another string</div>
```

When a user comes to view the post, I retrieve above content from DB and use lxml etree to do some stuff with content (which has nothing to do with my question) and return the content to browser.

```
from lxml import etree as ET
obj = ET.parse(StringIO.StringIO(self.text), parser=ET.HTMLParser()) #self.text holds the html string of blog post
return ET.tostring(tree) # return the html string to browser
```

now the problem is the content that is sent to browser as follows

```
<p>asdasd</p><p></em /><div>another string</div>
```

This causes all sort of problem with chrome browser, forinstance, at the users broswer, above html will be displayed as followed (after chrome automatically trying to fix it)

```
<p>asdasd</p><p></em><div>another string</div></em>
```

Is there a way to prevent lxml etree from changing the html content when parsing? it seems like etree does this to all empty html elements. ie if I put a 
`<div></div>` then that will be replaced with `<div />`

Comment: Why do you have empty opening and closing tags in your string in the first place?

Comment: I am doing testing to check if my blog post editor can handle edge cases. This is one of the edge cases where user clicks on italic icon on the writing pad and writing nothing, which leaves an empty <em> on the blog post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you want to try XML Canonicalization (C14N) in Python using lxml:

from this source https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n/ we read :

> Empty elements are converted to start-end tag pairs

**Sample code :**

```
from lxml import etree
xml = "<main><p>asdasd</p><p><em></em><div>another string</div></p></main>"
root_element = etree.XML(xml)
print(etree.tostring(root_element, method="c14n")))
```

**Output**

```
b'<main><p>asdasd</p><p><em></em><div>another string</div></p></main>'
```